# Rearranging the polynomial $x^3-23x^2+142x-120$ prior to factoring it

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

In the example 15: They are saying that,

$$x^3-23x^2+142x-120 = x^3-x^2-22x^2+22x+120x-120$$

From where did $22x^2$ and $22x$ come and also $120x$.

Please help me clear my confusion.

[image]

Comment: I think your question is not why that is true, but how did they arrive at such a splitting of terms. The answer to that is, of course, because they knew the roots (most likely). You can find the first root by using Rational Root Theorem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that
$$-23x^2=-x^2-22x^2$$
and that
$$142x=22x+120x.$$

So, we have

$$x^3\color{red}{-23x^2}+\color{blue}{142x}-120=x^3\color{red}{-x^2-22x^2}+\color{blue}{22x+120x}-120.$$

P.S. If you are asking the purpose (or background) of this rearrangement, then note that they noticed that
$$142-120=22,\ \ 23-22=1$$
and that the coefficients can be $1,-1,-22,22,120,-120$ from the left. This is of course to factor as
$$x^2(x-1)-22x(x-1)+120(x-1)=(x-1)(x^2-22x+120).$$

Answer (score 1):

They are breaking up $-23x^2$ as $-x^2-22x^2$, and they're breaking up $142x$ as $120x+22x$.  The purpose of this is to apply factoring by grouping in the next step.

Answer (score 0):

First of all note that's an identity (the $=$ is true).

Now, they decide to *rewrite* the original polynomial in that fashion in order to actually use partial factorisation (they are going to "collect" $x-1$ every two addends). It's just a trick you can use, nothing really deep.